# How to change Bootstrap dropdown background color & color in CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have been trying everything to change the background-color & color of the dropdown with no success (dropdown-menu & dropdown-item).  Now the background color of the dropdown is very light grey and the hover on each item has a medium light grey background and a yellow color which are not very contrasted and I need to change them.

```css
/* navbar */

.navbar-nav {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}


/* navbar bgn color */

.nav-item a,
.nav-item a:link,
.nav-item a:visited {
  color: var(--bodyPage) !important;
}


/* navbar item font color */

.nav-item a:hover,
.nav-item a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover) !important;
}


/* navbar item hover font color */

.active a,
.nav-item .active a:link,
.active a:visited {
  color: var(--navActive) !important;
}


/* active navbar item font color */

.active a:hover,
.active a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover) !important;
}


/* active navbar item hover font color */


/* links */

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: var(--link);
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover);
}

.site-footer a,
.site-footer a:link,
.site-footer a:visited {
  color: var(--link);
}


/* footer link color */

.site-footer a:hover,
.site-footer a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover);
}


/* footer hover link color */

.site-page a,
.site-page a:link,
.site-page a:visited {
  color: var(--link);
}


/* page body link color */

.site-page a:hover,
.site-page a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover);
}


/* page body hover link color */

.banner a,
.banner a:link,
.banner a:visited {
  color: var(--link);
}


/* banner link color */

.banner a:hover,
.banner a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover);
}


/* banner hover link color */

.no-banner a,
.no-banner a:link,
.no-banner a:visited {
  color: var(--link);
}


/* no banner link color */

.no-banner a:hover,
.no-banner a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover);
}


/* no banner hover link color */

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: red !important;
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    background-color: black !important;
    padding: 8px !important;
  }
}


/* dropdown menu */

.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: rgb(99, 97, 97) !important;
}

.dropdown-item a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".site-navbar-target" data-offset="300">
  <div class="site-wrap" id="home-section">
    <header class="container-fluid sticky site-header" id="headerSite">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="/dashboard" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a></li>
              <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownNav" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">database</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownNav">
                  <a href="..." class="dropdown-item">table1</a>
                  <a href="..." class="dropdown-item">table2</a>
                  <a href="..." class="dropdown-item">table3</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is your solution...**
***now it change successfully***
**i explain my to the comment of the code check please**
use this code to your css file or in the style tag then the dropdown will be changed...

```css
.dropdown {
            background-color: aqua !important;
            /* this is for dropdown background */
        }

        .dropdown a {
            color: whitesmoke !important;
            /* this is for dropdown text color */
        }

        .dropdown-menu {
            background-color: brown !important;
/* this is for dropdown menu background */
        }

        a.dropdown-item {
            color: blueviolet !important;
/* this is for dropdown menu text color */
        }

        a.dropdown-item:hover {
            background-color: chocolate;
            color: seagreen !important;
/* this is for dropdown menu hover background and text color */
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. "Here is your solution... now it change successfully" isn't enough

Comment: Switching to Bootstrap 5 and copy/pasting the examples from getbootstrap doesn't solve the problem he's facing.

Comment: first of all select the bootstrap class name like .dropdown then change the background color after the color value declare the important flag then it change the background color like this. 
`.dropdown {
            background-color: aqua !important;
            /* this is for dropdown background */
        }
`

`        .dropdown-menu {
            background-color: brown !important;
        }`
this code for the dropdown menu background color
 
`        a.dropdown-item {
            color: blueviolet !important;
        }`
this is menu text color

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a custom css file (e.g. style.css) and add reference to it below your bootstrap css reference (e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path-to-your-css-file/style.css">` )
2. Add a new class to custom class to the elements you want to modify and color that class as per your requirement.

e.g. `<a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle custom-dropdown" id="dropdownNav" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">database</a>`

3. You can do the same for dropdown-item too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got some HTML issues, and I wasn't able to even view the dropdown menu in your example.  This way works for me, and I can see the color changed in the dropdown menu. It's not clear what colors you want exactly, but this might get you there.

```css
/* navbar */

.navbar-nav {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}


/* navbar bgn color */

.nav-item a,
.nav-item a:link,
.nav-item a:visited {
  color: var(--bodyPage) !important;
}


/* navbar item font color */

.nav-item a:hover,
.nav-item a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover) !important;
}


/* navbar item hover font color */

.active a,
.nav-item .active a:link,
.active a:visited {
  color: var(--navActive) !important;
}


/* active navbar item font color */

.active a:hover,
.active a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover) !important;
}


/* active navbar item hover font color */


/* links */

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: var(--link);
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover);
}

.site-footer a,
.site-footer a:link,
.site-footer a:visited {
  color: var(--link);
}


/* footer link color */

.site-footer a:hover,
.site-footer a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover);
}


/* footer hover link color */

.site-page a,
.site-page a:link,
.site-page a:visited {
  color: var(--link);
}


/* page body link color */

.site-page a:hover,
.site-page a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover);
}


/* page body hover link color */

.banner a,
.banner a:link,
.banner a:visited {
  color: var(--link);
}


/* banner link color */

.banner a:hover,
.banner a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover);
}


/* banner hover link color */

.no-banner a,
.no-banner a:link,
.no-banner a:visited {
  color: var(--link);
}


/* no banner link color */

.no-banner a:hover,
.no-banner a:focus {
  color: var(--linkHover);
}


/* no banner hover link color */

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: red !important;
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    background-color: black !important;
    padding: 8px !important;
  }
}


/* dropdown menu */

.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: rgb(99, 97, 97) !important;
}

.dropdown-item a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<header class="site-wrap" id="home-section">
  <header class="container-fluid sticky site-header" id="headerSite">
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/dashboard" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a></li>            
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                database
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">table1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">table2</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">table3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Thank you.  My simple problem was that the css was not refreshing while the firefox dev tools was open... F9 worked!